# What are these weird blanks in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code on my Mac. But there are weird blanks on my editor. The screenshot is below here. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understand your question - those empty spaces look expected given how few lines of code you have and how short each line is.  Nevertheless, perhaps you are looking for this option :

```
// Controls if the editor will scroll beyond the last line
   "editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": true,
```

You can set that to false in your user or workplace settings if you wish to see less empty space at the end of your files (you are able to continue scrolling beyond the end of the file with the default setting).

Comment: If you look closer, I think he is referring to the discoloration of the boxes he is pointing at.